# Проверяемая гласная

Tags: орфография

Почему прочИтать, но прочЕсть? Это ведь однокоренные слова.

Answer (score 2):

В этих словах происходит чередование гласных: е/и

Правило

В корнях бер-/бир-, дер-/дир-, мер-/мир-, пер-/пир-, тер-/тир-, блест-/блист-, жег-/жиг-, стел-/стил-, **чет-/чит-** пишется буква **«и»,** если после корня следует суффикс **-а-.** В остальных случаях пишется буква «е».